# How operator <=> compare the objects?

Tags: php, php-7, spaceship-operator

In the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) given this example:

> ```
> // only values are compared
> $a = (object) ["a" => "b"]; 
> $b = (object) ["b" => "b"]; 
> echo $a <=> $b; // 0
> ```

But when I execute it I get 1 as output back:

```
$a = (object) ["a" => "b"];
$b = (object) ["b" => "b"];
echo $a <=> $b; //1
```

I don't understood now how <=> compares the objects? In  the RFC it says that it is compared only  by values.

*P.S. i use PHP 7.0.4-6+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS ) under vagrant*

UPD:

```
php > echo (object)["b"=>"b"] <=> (object)["b"=>"b"];
0
php > echo (object)["b"=>"b"] <=> (object)["a"=>"b"];
1
php > echo (object)["a"=>"b"] <=> (object)["b"=>"b"];
1
```

Comment: I guess it compares keys and values. In the example, the object have same key and value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When reading the [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/combined-comparison-operator) we find out that it contradicts itself:

> Add a new operator (expr) <=> (expr), it returns 0 if both operands are equal, 1 if the left is greater, and -1 if the right is greater. It **uses exactly the same comparison rules** as used by our existing comparison operators: <, <=, ==, >= and >. (See the manual for details)

**Note:** See the `==`, this means the spaceship operator does a loosely comparison.

And later down in the examples:

> ```
> // only values are compared
> $a = (object) ["a" => "b"]; 
> $b = (object) ["b" => "b"]; 
> echo $a  $b; // 0
> ```

The spaceship operator is just a combination of the operators `<`, `==` and `>`. And it gives respective return values depending on what it evaluates to:

```
operator(s):   <  =  >
return value: -1  0  1
```

Now [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) are a bit more complex [types](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.intro.php). To understand what the `<=>` PHP spaceship operator does, we need to look and understand how `<`, `==` and `>` work for arrays and objects.

---

So let's look at the comparison operators `<`, `>`, `==` for each type. First we will look at `<` and `>` and then after that we also look at `==`.

## Array comparison operators

Now as for arrays `<` and `>` are documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> ```
> ┌───────────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │ type of   │ type of   │                                                  │
> │ Operand 1 │ Operand 2 │ Result                                           │
> ├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ array     │ array     │ Array with fewer members is smaller,             │
> │           │           │ if key from operand 1 is not found in operand 2  │
> │           │           │ then arrays are uncomparable,                    │
> │           │           │ otherwise - compare value by value               │
> └───────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

This can also be written and represented by [code](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-136):

> Example #2 Transcription of standard array comparison
>
> ```
> <?php
> // Arrays are compared like this with standard comparison operators
> function standard_array_compare($op1, $op2)
> {
>     if (count($op1) < count($op2)) {
>         return -1; // $op1 < $op2
>     } elseif (count($op1) > count($op2)) {
>         return 1; // $op1 > $op2
>     }
>     foreach ($op1 as $key => $val) {
>         if (!array_key_exists($key, $op2)) {
>             return null; // uncomparable
>         } elseif ($val < $op2[$key]) {
>             return -1;
>         } elseif ($val > $op2[$key]) {
>             return 1;
>         }
>     }
>     return 0; // $op1 == $op2
> }
> ?>
> ```

We can test this easily with some testing. Using [methods like in math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_proof#Methods) and always change only one thing, so we can make sure we are correct here:

```js
/**
/*
/* Testing operators: < and >
/*
 */ 

//Test case
//Variations: amount, values and keys (order)
//Test count: 9
//    Failed: 0
//    Passed: 9    
{
    //Test case 1.1
    $a = [1];
    $b = [1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, keys and values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
   
    //Test case 1.2
    $a = [1];
    $b = [1, 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same amount of elements, but same values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));

    //Test case 1.3 
    $a = [10];
    $b = [1, 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same amount of elements nor values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.4
    $a = [1 => 1];
    $b = [10 => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of element and values, NOT same keys: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));

    //Test case 1.5
    $a = [10];
    $b = [1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and keys, NOT same values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.6
    $a = [1 => 1, 2 => 1];
    $b = [2 => 1, 1 => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and keys in different order: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.7
    $a = [1 => 1, 2 => 5];
    $b = [2 => 5];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same values, NOT same amount of elements nor keys: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.8
    $a = [10 => 1];
    $b = [1 => 10];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same keys nor values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.9
    $a = [1 => 1, 2 => 1];
    $b = [2 => 10, 1 => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and values, NOT same keys nor order: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
}


echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;  //Test case separator

/**
/*
/* Test case end
/*
 */

//NULL, TRUE, FALSE 2 str func
function bool2str($v){if($v === NULL)return "NULL";elseif($v === FALSE)return "FALSE";elseif($v === TRUE)return "TRUE";else return "UNEXPECTED: '$v'";}
```

For the equality/identity operators `==` and `===` we find the documentation for arrays [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

> ```
> ┌───────────┬──────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │ Example   │ Name     │ Result                                           │
> ├───────────┼──────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ $a == $b  │ Equality │ TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs. │
> │ $a === $b │ Identity │ TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs  │
> │           │          │ in the same order and of the same types.         │
> └───────────┴──────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

As before we can simply test this with some testing code:

```js
/**
/*
/* Testing operators: == and ===
/*
 */ 

//Test case
//Variations: amount, values and keys (order)
//Test count: 5
//    Failed: 0
//    Passed: 5     
{
    //Test case 2.1
    $a = [1];
    $b = [1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, values and keys: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
   
    //Test case 2.2
    $a = [1];
    $b = [10, 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same amount of elements, but same values: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));

    //Test case 2.3
    $a = [10];
    $b = [1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, but not values: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
    //Test case 2.4
    $a = [1 => 1];
    $b = [10 => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and values, but not keys: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
    //Test case 2.5
    $a = [1 => 1, 2 => 2];
    $b = [2 => 2, 1 => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, key and values, but different order: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
}


echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;  //Test case separator

/**
/*
/* Test case end
/*
 */

//NULL, TRUE, FALSE 2 str func
function bool2str($v){if($v === NULL)return "NULL";elseif($v === FALSE)return "FALSE";elseif($v === TRUE)return "TRUE";else return "UNEXPECTED: '$v'";}
```

So we can see and confirm that the comparison operators for arrays work as expected and as documented!

<sub>[Full Testing File](http://pastebin.com/kFSis9rd)</sub>

## Object comparison operators

The documentation for `<`
 and `>` with objects is documented [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> ```
> ┌───────────┬───────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
> │ type of   │ type of   │                                                  │
> │ Operand 1 │ Operand 2 │ Result                                           │
> ├───────────┼───────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
> │ object    │ object    │ Built-in classes can define its own comparison,  │  
> │           │           │ different classes are uncomparable,              │
> │           │           │ same class compare properties same as arrays     │
> └───────────┴───────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
> ```

As before we can also test this:

```js
/**
/*
/* Testing operators: < and >
/*
 */ 

//Test case
//Variations: amount, values and keys (order)
//Test count: 10
//    Failed: 0
//    Passed: 10    
{
    //Test case 1.1
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = (object)["a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, keys and values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
   
    //Test case 1.2
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = (object)["a" => 1, "b" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same amount of elements, but same values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));

    //Test case 1.3 
    $a = (object)["a" => 10];
    $b = (object)["a" => 1, "b" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same amount of elements nor values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.4
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = (object)["b" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of element and values, NOT same keys: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));

    //Test case 1.5
    $a = (object)["a" => 10];
    $b = (object)["a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and keys, NOT same values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.6
    $a = (object)["a" => 1, "b" => 1];
    $b = (object)["b" => 1, "a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and keys in different order: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.7
    $a = (object)["a" => 1, "b" => 5];
    $b = (object)["b" => 5];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same values, NOT same amount of elements nor keys: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.8
    $a = (object)["c" => 1];
    $b = (object)["a" => 10];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same keys nor values: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.9
    $a = (object)["a" => 1, "b" => 1];
    $b = (object)["b" => 10, "a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and values, NOT same keys nor order: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
    //Test case 1.10
    class A {public $a = 1;}
    $a = new A;
    class B {public $a = 1;}
    $b = new B;

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and values and keys, but different  not built-in class: " . "'<' -> " . bool2str($a < $b) . " '>' -> " . bool2str($a > $b));
    
}


echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;  //Test case separator

/**
/*
/* Test case end
/*
 */

//NULL, TRUE, FALSE 2 str func
function bool2str($v){if($v === NULL)return "NULL";elseif($v === FALSE)return "FALSE";elseif($v === TRUE)return "TRUE";else return "UNEXPECTED: '$v'";}
```

The documentation for `==` and `===` with objects has its own page [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.object-comparison.php#language.oop5.object-comparison):

> When using the comparison operator (==), object variables are compared in a simple manner, namely: Two object instances are equal if they have the same attributes and values, and are instances of the same class.
>
> When using the identity operator (===), object variables are identical if and only if they refer to the same instance of the same class.

And again this can be tested:

```js
/**
/*
/* Testing operators: == and ===
/*
 */ 

//Test case
//Variations: amount, values and keys (order)
//Test count: 7
//    Failed: 0
//    Passed: 7    
{
    //Test case 2.1
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = (object)["a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, values and keys: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
   
    //Test case 2.2
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = (object)["a" => 10, "b" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("NOT same amount of elements, but same values: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));

    //Test case 2.3
    $a = (object)["a" => 10];
    $b = (object)["a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, but not values: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
    //Test case 2.4
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = (object)["b" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and values, but not keys: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
    //Test case 2.5
    $a = (object)["a" => 1, "b" => 2];
    $b = (object)["b" => 2, "a" => 1];

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements, key and values, but different order: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
    //Test case 2.6
    class C {public $a = 1;}
    $a = new A;
    class D {public $a = 1;}
    $b = new B;

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same amount of elements and values and keys, but different  not built-in class: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
    //Test case 2.7
    $a = (object)["a" => 1];
    $b = $a;

    //Passed
    var_dump("Same exact instance: " . "'==' -> " . bool2str($a == $b) . " '===' -> " . bool2str($a === $b));
    
}


echo PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;  //Test case separator

/**
/*
/* Test case end
/*
 */

//NULL, TRUE, FALSE 2 str func
function bool2str($v){if($v === NULL)return "NULL";elseif($v === FALSE)return "FALSE";elseif($v === TRUE)return "TRUE";else return "UNEXPECTED: '$v'";}
```

So we see, that the comparison operators with objects behave exactly like expected and documented! Even with loose comparison the attributes and values are being considered.

<sub>[Full Testing File](http://pastebin.com/Q2p5iqx9)</sub>

---

## Conclusion

As this bug has been reported [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69466), the bug report is probably based on the comment in the RFC, which says:

> // only values are compared

But besides that this is the only example in the RFC with a comment, the RFC clearly states that it uses the same comparison rules as `<`, `==` and `>`.

This means that the code example provided would be uncomparable, because it doesn't have the same attributes/keys.

As for equality it would need same attributes/keys and values so it can't be equal, and for less- or greater- than it is uncomparable as shown in the code example above how the comparison works:

```
if (!array_key_exists($key, $op2)) {
    return null; // uncomparable
}
```

We also see this if we try each comparison operator alone:

```
$a = (object)["b" => "b"]; 
$b = (object)["a" => "b"]; 


var_dump($a > $b);   //FALSE
var_dump($a < $b);   //FALSE
var_dump($a == $b);  //FALSE
```

All return false, since it's uncomparable.

And just for the case `StdClass` would have its own comparison, we can test it with our own class:

```js
class A {
public $a = "";
public $b = "";
}

$a = new A;
$a->a = "b";
unset($a->b);

$b = new A;
$b->b = "b";
unset($b->a);

var_dump($a);
var_dump($b);

var_dump($a <=> $b); //1
```

Also same output: 1.

**So I would say since it is uncomparable it shouldn't return `0`, `1` nor `-1`. It should probably return `FALSE` or `NULL` or something like this.**

Right now I would say this behaviour isn't documented correctly.

Comment: @user3254021 Please see my answer again, I updated the answer completely.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $object1 <=> $object2; // 0
```

This should return `0` only if

- `$object1` and `$object2` are instances of the same class
- *and* they have the same attributes and values.

In you example, I'd surprised if it return `0` instead of `1`.
Maybe a typo in the RFC?

Comment: The objects are the same in the RFC example.

Comment: @user3254021, good question... I really don't know. After reading the bug linked by Rizier123 I don't know if the php internals realized a mistake in the RFC or a bug to fix in the implementation... I hope it's a mistake in the RFC, becouse it doesn't match the behaviour of the [comparision object](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.object-comparison.php) in php.