# PHP array_column() not returning object falsy values

Tags: php, php-7

I'm sure this is expected behavior for `array_column()`:

```
class myObj {
    public $prop;
    public function __construct(int $prop) {
        $this->prop = $prop;
    }
}

$objects = [
    new myObj(7),
    new myObj(3),
    new myObj(8),
    new myObj(0),
    new myObj(2),
    new myObj(6)
];

echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_column($objects, 'prop'));
echo '</pre>';
```

Returns:

```
Array (
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 8
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 6
)
```

The `0` is missing. Maybe it uses `empty()` internally..?

Why would it not return falsy values when `0` and `false` can be normal valid object property values, and `array_column()` is meant for returning values..?

What's the best work around..?

Comment: Seems like a bug for me.

Comment: which PHP version?

Comment: PHP 7.0.0 on Windows/IIS...

Comment: Reproduced on PHP 7.0.4 in Ubuntu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It certainly seems like a bug, and I'd [report it as such](https://bugs.php.net/)

You can work round it by converting the object array to a nested array:

```
print_r(array_column(json_decode(json_encode($objects), true), 'prop'));
```

Comment: I don't know much about the PHP internals, but I think it is because of this: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_7_0/ext/standard/array.c#3569 where it skips the "empty" PHP values. I also could be wrong

Comment: @Rizier123 - that looks as though it would have the effect of eliminating any value that compares with null (and the bug also affects valid nulls and boolean false).... better to simply test if the property exists; I might do a PR this weekend

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant with *"empty" PHP values* :) I also tested it with an empty string which didn't showed up in the result. Sadly I don't know enough about the internals that I could fix it.

Comment: Also there seems to be other problems with `array_column()` in PHP 7 with objects: https://3v4l.org/tRnlr It does not see to work with integer properties. Same for invalid property names: https://3v4l.org/CDvPC

Comment: How do you fix an elephpant? One bug at a time :)

Comment: Voted on it. Seems like you are a bit more involved into the internals, so maybe this is interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36246993 I'm not 100%  sure if this is also a PHP bug or if I missed something there.